# Ruby error: cannot load such file -- rest-client

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rest-client

I am using Ruby on Rails 4.

I am trying to

```
require 'rest-client'
```

in my controller so that I can parse the login information I am getting from a form and send it to an API.

I can verify that the gem is installed and is also in my Gemfile on the application root.

However, it is still throwing the "cannot load such file -- rest-client " when I try to require the file in my controller.

I have googled the error and most of the answers I saw were either the gem wasn't installed, wasn't in the Gemfile, or a combination of both those. Neither is the situation here.

Is my controller unable to access the rest-client gem for some reason? I have to use rest-client because it is required in the API.

This is the line I used to install the gem:

```
gem install rest-client
```

This is the homepage of the gem: https://github.com/archiloque/rest-client
Which just redirects you to https://github.com/rest-client/rest-client

I should also note that it works fine when I wasn't using the code in a Rails project but just running the commands in the Terminal.

Comment: According to the github documentation you ned to do require 'rest_client' with an underscore.

Comment: I made that change with the same resultant error.

Comment: It shows up in the bundle. Restarting the server did it. Thanks Abe.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Assuming you're using https://github.com/rest-client/rest-client *(since you didn't specify)*, your `require` line should be

```
require 'rest-client'
```

according to the [README](https://github.com/rest-client/rest-client/blob/master/README.md). Also, make sure you restart your rails server after adding the gem to your `Gemfile` and running `bundle`.

Comment: This is no more applicable

Comment: Well it was posted nearly 3 years ago. Feel free to suggest an edit if you have an alteration to make it relevant.

Comment: Well you can't do a 1 character edit :) , please change this from `require 'rest_client'` to `require rest-client`

Answer (score 8):

Run the following command in your terminal:

```
gem install rest-client
```

and use `require 'rest-client'`. No need to change to rest_client.

Answer (score 6):

in my case, none of the solutions in this thread worked
what did work, was to add the gem directly in the `Gemfile`:

```
 gem 'rest-client'
```

after closing the `rails server`, exiting `rails console` and running `bundle install`,
I opened again the `rails console` and this time `require 'rest-client'` worked flawlessly

Answer (score 1):

For me it was an issue with bundle (which I thought I had installed). Spoiler alert, I didn't, and this is how I fixed it. I'm on a Mac running OS X Yosemite and my terminal version is Darwin Kernel Version 14.3.0:

```
cd
gem install bundler
```

or

```
cd
sudo gem install bundler
```

If you get something along the lines of the following error:

ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::FilePermissionError)
    You don't have write permissions for the /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0 directory.

Finally, change your require line from:

```
require 'rest-client'
```

to

```
require 'rest_client'
```

Then run your code!

Answer (score 0):

First ensure you have installed `gem 'rest-client'`, ~> **1.8.0** on your gem file. Run bundle install and then `require 'rest_client'`. This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Add require 'rest-client' to your top of controller and restart server

Comment: please add sample code which helps others also to understand.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

Try `require 'rest_client'`, instead of `require 'rest-client'`